# #pragma alloc_text(PAGE, functionname)

Tags: windows, winapi, pragma, virtual-memory

```
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, foo)

void foo() { }
```

This code is usually used in device drivers.
The *foo* function will be swapped whenever system needs.

Questions.

- Does it work in user space code? Will the function be also paged?
- Without the pragma, I mean by default, are all kernel level functions allocated nonpaged memory?
- Does PE file loader decide where the functions are allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User mode programs are swapped by default. It is unusual that you would need something else. Sounds like a device driver requirement to be resident to handle interrupts or such things. User mode programs don't do that.

Comment: Then, how do we do user mode code(text) can not be swapped? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know, have never had to try that. It would anyway be very impolite for one application to grab physical memory for itself, and leave less for everybody else. The non-paged memory is really intended for interrupt handlers and such, where you just cannot handle a page fault interrupt on top of what you already got.

Comment: you are right. It's just qurious. User mode data can be locked with VirtualLock. It will never page out. I guess we can also make user-mode functions(TEXT) which aren't swapped.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile a simple hello world driver, then you will see that the PE (Portable Executable) section called '.text' will have the 'Not pageable' characteristics flag set. So yes, by default, all driver code is in that section unless you mark it as being pageable, which will make it end up in the 'PAGE' section instead of the '.text' section.